# Is one of my ancestors display:none?

Tags: css, html, dom

Is there a way to know if one of an element's ancestors is display:none without traversing up the DOM Tree?

Comment: If some ancestor has `display: none`, then all of it's content will be hidden, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are wondering how to do that from inside a JavaScript code? If so then you can use jQuery's is(':visible') function. If not I am posting it for future users who might be looking for this.

```
$("#selector").is(":visible") // returns true or false
```

It checks for the following conditions.

- Style is to `display:none`
- Form `input` elements with `type="hidden"`
- `width` and `height` set to 0px.
- If any parent has style is to `display:none`

Answer (score 1):

There are not ready-made way to check `display: none` on parent elements using [Vanilla JS™](http://vanilla-js.com/), because:

1. You do not have access to an `Array` containing all the parent elements of an element (not unti [`:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#has-pseudo) is adopted, then use it with `querySelectorAll()`).
2. `display` is a [non-inherited property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance#Non-inherited_properties), which makes `getComputedStyle()` a no-go (and even this had worked, it would not be able to detect interrupted inheritance).

You'll have to traverse.